# Manually insert post into MULTISITE database: Need to specify the TABLE

Tags: multisite, wp-insert-post

I need to manually insert a post into multisite database. I'm using the variables listed here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

...and have been able to insert a post into the MAIN (parent) site.

I now need to add a post to one of the sub-sites. How can I specify the table where the new post should go?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me:
- uploaded the file into site root
- ran it from the subsite, like this: http://subsite.mainsite.com/my-script.php

It ended up inserting the new post into the subsite.